# Computing Covariance for Two Coordinates of an Rth-Dimensional Vector

Tags: probability, vector-spaces

I'm reading a paper that shows Pearson's Theorem for Chi Square by constructing a vector with properties that match the relevant distribution (specifically, its mean and covariance). I'm stuck on their computation of covariance for the i'th and j'th coordinates of this vector:

[image]

Can anyone shed light on this calculation? The paper I'm referring to can be accessed more fully here, in case I've left out any important background that isn't included in the image:
(https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture11.pdf)

P.S. "p" refers to the probability that an object will be placed in the r'th category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider each term in the expression $\displaystyle \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( g_i - \sum_{l = 1}^r g_l \sqrt{p_l} \sqrt{p_i} \right) \left( g_j - \sum_{l = 1}^r g_l \sqrt{p_l} \sqrt{p_j} \right)\right]$.

The first term is given by $\mathbb{E}[g_i g_j] = 0$ as gaussians are independent.

The second term is given as $\displaystyle \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{l = 1}^r g_l g_j \sqrt{p_l} \sqrt{p_i}\right]$. Again since the Gaussians are independent, $\mathbb{E}[g_l g_j] = 0$ for $l \neq j$ and for $l = j$, $\mathbb{E}[g_l g_j] = \mathbb{E}[g_j^2] =  1$ giving us $\sqrt{p_i}\sqrt{p_j}$.

The third term would be $\displaystyle \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{l = 1}^r g_l g_i \sqrt{p_l} \sqrt{p_j}\right]$ and using the same steps as in the previous case we know it equals $\sqrt{p_j}\sqrt{p_i}$.

The last term is given as $\displaystyle \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{l = 1}^r \sum_{k = 1}^r g_l g_k \sqrt{p_l} \sqrt{p_k} \sqrt{p_j} \sqrt{p_i}\right]$. Again the terms would be zero if $l \neq k$ and if $l = k$, it would be $1$. This reduces the fourth term to be $\displaystyle \sum_{l = 1}^r \sqrt{p_l} \sqrt{p_l} \sqrt{p_j} \sqrt{p_i} =  \sqrt{p_j} \sqrt{p_i} \sum_{l = 1}^r p_l =  \sqrt{p_j} \sqrt{p_i}$ where we used $p_i$'s formed a probability distribution. Combining all the terms with the appropriate signs should give the required answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's all clear now